# Creating meta object in API response

Tags: loopbackjs

How do I make my API response in the following format using loopbackJS.

```
{
"meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": "/api/Questions/?limit=20&offset=20",
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 215
},
"objects": [...]
}
```

Comment: I have created defined my model schema in model.json, and added some remote methods on model.js. Do you need the exact code format?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the response, I'm using an `afterRemote` [remote hook](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks) to handle it.

Here's an example of `common/models/car.js` to get you started.

```
module.exports = function(Car) {
  // before the static .find methods
  Car.afterRemote('**', function(ctx, car, next) {
    console.log(ctx.methodString, 'was invoked remotely');
    if(ctx.result) {
      var result = ctx.result;
      ctx.result = {
        objects: result,
        meta: {
          limit: 20,
          next: ctx.req.baseUrl,
          offset: 0,
          previous: '',
        }
      };
      if(Array.isArray(ctx.result.objects)) {
        ctx.result.meta.count = ctx.result.objects.length;
      }
    }
    next();
  });
};
```

With that code you get an output like this:

```
{"objects":[
    {"model":"Nissan","make":"Leaf","year":2013,"id":1},
    {"model":"Telsa","make":"S","year":2014,"id":2},
    {"model":"Chevrolet","make":"Volt","year":2014,"id":3},
    {"model":"Toyota","make":"Prius C","year":2015,"id":4}
],
"meta":{
    "limit":20,
    "next":"/api/cars",
    "offset":0,
    "previous":"",
    "count":4
}}
```